# Cleaning Cobalt with Dodecylbenzene Sulphonic Acid

Tags: metal, cleaning

Here in Brazil we use a special detergent to clean up metals, based on **Dodecylbenzene Sulphonic Acid**, it is *very effective at shining up all sorts of different metals*.

I recently acquired 2 samples of 99.99% **pure metallic cobalt** for my element collection...
They were covered in some sort of weird blackish-grey-green-brown residue...

I then dumped the 2 pieces of Co in a small container with this special dish detergent... to my surprise, this blackish residue *immediatelly started to come off*. After some time, I was left with very shiny pieces of Cobalt.

Did some reaction actually take place here? What reaction? Thanks in advance.
As I understand, Cobalt is meant to be rather resistant to acids/corrosion in general.

Comment: The detergent is acid, probably dissolving cobalt oxides.

Comment: Funny. It seemed like some sort of residue or dirt coming off of the metal.

Comment: "based on"? Typical detergents are *salts* of alkylbenzenesulphonic acids. I think that's the kind of being based on. Acid itself would be highly unlikely and I wouldn't call it a detergent.

Comment: On the label of the detergent, the active ingredients listed are **"dodecylbenzene sulfonic acid and glycolic acid"**.

Comment: These detergents are sold here as *"Brilha Alumínio"* - or somethink like *"Aluminum Shine"* in english.

I've been able to clean up several types of metals with it... Like Copper, in which the result is instantaneous, Bismuth, Aluminum and of course, Cobalt.